# Inheritance and function selection

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

i think i have a common probelm but i dont know which programming pattern solves it.

I have a class that sends packages via Udp. `udpSender` has a a function `sendPaypload()`

I also have a `tcpSender` class that also has a function `sendPayload()`

At last i have a class `executor` with many many functions that configure a remote device by sending byte arrays eigther via TCP or UDP
it inherites from `udpSender` and uses the `executor:udpSender.sendPayload()` function from it to configure the other device.
I can also inherit from the `tcpSender` and do the same and both work fine,

but how can i change between the UDP and TCP sender functionalty when i create the `executor` object instead of having to change the baseclass before the build.

Comment: Seems like you could inject the sender as a dependency of the executor (in its constructor for instance)

Comment: seems rather opinion based, so IMHO just create a generic executor class `executor<TExecute> where TExecute : IExecute { }` - and use it like this `(new executor<udpSender>()).sendPayload();` - or declare only the method generic `(new executor()).sendPayload<udpSender>();` or ....

Comment: @RandRandom "seems rather opinion based", hence "could" and not "should"

Comment: Are you sure you want an abstraction of the TCP/UDP layer? If the transport layer is unreliable it could very easily affect the application layer. Abstracting over say TCP/QUIC might be more useful, since both provide reliable transfer. Or just use a higher level protocol that would likely be easier to use.

Comment: @JonasH I have a hardware constraint on the other end that does not have a tcp ip stack, just a limited ip stack that supports udp based traffic

Comment: My point remains, if your targeted device does not have builtin tcp support you should either use a protocol on top of UDP that provide reliability, or just let the application layer handle unreliable transport. In the later case you should probably just always use UDP. Trying to provide an abstraction over things that are fundamentally different is quite dangerous.

Comment: we implemented a handshake based protocol on the UDP lnterface. Thanks for pointing out, but that did not seem to matter for the question i had on which pattern solves my implemenation issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this is to have both your `udpSender` and your `tcpSender` implement an interface with the method `sendPaypload()`, and inject them as a dependency to your `executor` class. Something like this:

```
interface ISender
{
    void SendPayload();
}

class UdpSender : ISender {/* implementation */}

class TcpSender : ISender {/* implementation */}

class Executor
{
    private ISender _sender;
    public Executor(ISender sender) => _sender = sender;

    // Rest of the code goes here
}
```

Comment: `The simplest way to...` should be `The IMHO simplest way to...`

Comment: simpler than using generics, IMHO....

Comment: thanks i ll try if this does what i want it too and be back asap

Comment: okay.... seems like your ego needed that statement...

Comment: @RandRandom Feel free to suggest a simpler way, if you think there is one. I might learn something new. It's not a question of ego, I really don't think there's a simpler way than using polymorphism for this type of problems - but then again, I might be wrong.

Comment: that does indeed do the trick for me, thanks a lot!